# Unable to spread the header and footer to the entire browser length

Tags: html, css

This CSS code leaves the left bit of the browser uncovered in the header and footer...

```
  header {
    float:left;
    height: 65px;
    background: #303030;
    font-family:'Comic Sans MS';
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    min-width:100%;
  }
  footer {
    height: 65px;
    background: #303030;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    min-width:100%;
  }
```

what is the problem in the code so that i can spread it entirely covering the width of the browser...?

Comment: Position fixed and floated left??

Comment: i saw that too, but i havent done web design in a while and couldnt remember if that was bad

Comment: Why are you floating full width header with fixed position? Why `min-width`? set `width: 100%;`. Also put `top: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: I hope this is for a website discussing how terrible `Comic Sans` is

Comment: Sorry guys...This was my mistake....just left:0 will do it...Next time i'll do more research before putting up such questions...

Answer (score 1):

specify the **left** property for header and footer

```
  header {
    height: 65px;
    background: #303030;
    font-family:'Comic Sans MS';
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    min-width:100%;
    left: 0; /*this one*/
    top: 0;
  }
  footer {
    height: 65px;
    background: #303030;
    position:fixed;
    min-width:100%;
    left: 0; /*this one*/
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

please see the example below

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/witpl)

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've done web-design, however I don't think float left with position fixed will stretch it. if anything it will make it dynamic. at any rate, a quick google search unearthed this: stackoverflow.com/questions/2309819/how-to-stretch-a-header-across-a-web-page-background-with-css

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It's really more of a comment, or a link to a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have not reseted some browser default settings, add this you your css:

```
html, body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

I recommend you to use a css reset such as this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution to the problem is

```
header {
    height: 65px;
    background: #303030;
    font-family:'Comic Sans MS';
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
  }
  footer {
    height: 65px;
    background: #303030;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    min-width:100%;
  }
```